# Manage Visual studio 2012 Database project for a specific schema, not entire database?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, database-project

In a database, there is a schema for each module. Each schema has several objects(Tables,views..). 
Ex: School Database. It has 3 modules students, staff and training and respective schema's as students schema, staff schema, training schema.**None of them are managed through database project**

```
Student.Table1
Staff.Table1
Training.Table1
Training.Table2
```

Now there is a new module *certification*, and would like to create new schema called certification and manage it through database project. Since, I have no control over other schema's would like to ignore them in database project which I want to create and manage for certification.

I did some research find concepts like partisan schema & composite schema in vs 2010. But it seems they are obsolete with vs2012 database project.**Can someone guide me how to achieve this?**

Comment: Will the rest of the DB change while you are maintaining just this schema? Is there a way you can capture those other changes if necessary?

Comment: @PeterSchott Yes,rest of the DB can change. No, And I'm not concerned for those changes. All I care about the schema that I create.

Comment: Mostly asking for reference questions - you could need to reference those objects and if so, build a dacpac for them or something like that. There should be some partial project support w/ SSDT, but Jamie Thomson's articles are the way to get started there.

Answer (score 0):

In your database project, just create your 'certification' schema and all of the objects (tables, views, etc.) for that schema. When you publish the project, make sure you set these options as follows:

- Disable "Always re-create database"
- Disable "DROP objects in target but not in project"

Disabling those options will ensure that objects in the other schemas will not get deleted.

Comment: I'll try and let you know.